# Algorithm to find all points on a 2D grid some distance away from another point

Tags: grid, 2d, distance, point

I have some point on a 2D grid (x, y) and I need to find all points that are n distance away from that point. The way I'm measuring distance is by using the distance formula between the two points. Anyone know how to do this?

Edit: Just for reference, what I'm trying to do is to write some AI path finding that will maintain some distance away from a target in a system that uses grid based locations. Currently I'm using A* path finding, but I'm not sure if that matters or makes a difference since I'm kind of new to this stuff.

Comment: Do you want points that are within that range or exactly that distance away?

Comment: The ideal solution would be all points that are exactly or within some margin of error of the distance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what I would do:

1. First filter out all points that are further than D on either x or y.  These are certainly outside the circle of radius D.  This is a much simpler computation, and it can quickly eliminate a lot of work.  This is a outer bounding-box optimization.
2. You can also use an inner bounding-box optimization.  If the points are closer than D * sqrt(2)/2 on either x or y, then they're certainly within the circle of radius D.  This is also cheaper than calculating the distance formula.
3. Then you have a smaller number of candidate points that *may* be within the circle of radius D.  For these, use the distance formula.  Remember that if D = sqrt(Δx<sup>2</sup>+Δy<sup>2</sup>), then D<sup>2</sup> = Δx<sup>2</sup>+Δy<sup>2</sup>.
   So you can skip the cost of calculating square root.

---

So in pseudocode, you could do the following:

```
for each point
begin
    if test 1 indicates the point is outside the outer bounding box, 
    then skip this point

    if test 2 indicates the point is inside the inner bounding box, 
    then keep this point

    if test 3 indicates the point is inside the radius of the circle, 
    then keep this point
end
```

Comment: You can further optimize the algorithm by using spatial indexes. This will be true if the number of points is really high. If the number of points is not that big, the cost of constructing the spatial index may not be worth.

Comment: The grid isn't very large. I think the current planned size of the world is only going to be around 256x256.

Comment: OK, so first I would filter the points that have both their X and Y distance within the distance, then filter those points using the inner bounding-box check? Not sure how to use the second part.

Comment: Sweet, thanks for that :) I need to do some simple testing to make sure I'm getting the values I want but I think this might be exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is known as range query. The brute force solution is just as you described: computed the distance of all points from the reference point and return those whose distance is less than the desired range value.

The brute force algorithm is O(N^2). There are, however, more efficient algorithms that employ [spatial indexes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spatial_index) to reduce algorithm complexity and the number of distance calculations. For example, you can use a [R-Tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R-tree) to index your points.

Answer (score 0):

Its called nearest neighbor search. More at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nearest_neighbor_search

There are open libraries for that. I have used one written for C and recommend it: http://www.cs.umd.edu/~mount/ANN/. ANN stands for Approximate Nearest Neighbor, however, you can turn the approximation off and find the exact nearest neighbors.

Comment: Interesting stuff, but I think it's far too heavy for what I'm currently doing. I'll keep it in mind for later stuff though.

Answer (score 0):

This wouldn't use the distance formula, but if you're looking for points exactly n distance  away, perhaps you could use sin/cos?

In pseudocode:

```
for degrees in range(360):
    x = cos(degrees) * n
    y = sin(degrees) * n
    print x, y
```

That would print every point n away in 360 degree increments.

Answer (score 0):

Java implementation:

```
public static Set<Point> findNearbyPoints(Set<Point> pts, Point centerPt, double radius) {
    Set<Point> nearbyPtsSet = new HashSet<Point>();
    double innerBound = radius * (Math.sqrt(2.0) / 2.0);
    double radiusSq = radius * radius;
    for (Point pt : pts) {
        double xDist = Math.abs(centerPt.x - pt.x);
        double yDist = Math.abs(centerPt.y - pt.y);
        if (xDist > radius || yDist > radius)
            continue;
        if (xDist > innerBound || yDist > innerBound)
            continue;
        if (distSq(centerPt, pt) < radiusSq)
            nearbyPtsSet.add(pt);
    }
    return nearbyPtsSet;
}
```